# Postgresql Constraint CHECK conditional

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with columns: c1, c2, c3, c4
And I am trying to add a CONSTRAINT check
The conditions are:

1. if c4 is not null then c1,c2,c3 all must not null.
2. else if c4 is null then c1,c2,c3 are optional but at least one field
   must be non-null.

Here is my sql command:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT quatereulchk CHECK( 
    (c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) 
    OR 
    (c4 IS NULL AND c1 IS NOT NULL OR c2 IS NOT NULL OR c3 IS NOT NULL)
    );
```

I tested with pg_admin however the constrain is not working. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: check precedence of `AND` and `OR`. If we talked about maths your DDL expects that `2 * 2 + 2` equals to `8`

Comment: I see, in my case is that means AND is higher than OR? Thank you for your hint!

Comment: Yep (and not only in this case but everywhere)

Comment: Cool! problem solved. Thank you! BTW really like the way of answering question, giving hint instead of giving answer. In that way I could understand why problem happens, rather than copy and paste. Really NO offends to other people who answered my question.  Thank you all!

Comment: "BTW really like the way of answering question, giving hint instead of giving answer." --- that's nice to hear :-) Unfortunately very few people here respect that

Comment: The website is based on the idea of answering questions. It's hard to blame people that follow that plan.

Comment: @klin it depends. The "give me the codes" question is far from "give me a hint" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try grouping the "c1 IS NOT NULL OR c2 IS NOT NULL OR c3 IS NOT NULL" in the second case, for example:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT quatereulchk CHECK( (c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND (c1 IS NOT NULL OR c2 IS NOT NULL OR c3 IS NOT NULL)) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT quatereulchk CHECK( 
    (c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) 
    OR 
    (c4 IS NULL AND COALESCE(c1, c2, c3) IS NOT NULL)
    );
```

Some tests:

```
insert into example values
(null, null, null, null);
ERROR:  new row for relation "example" violates check constraint "quatereulchk"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null).

insert into example values
(null, null, 3, null);
INSERT 0 1

insert into example values
(null, 2, 3, 4);
ERROR:  new row for relation "example" violates check constraint "quatereulchk"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2, 3, 4).

insert into example values
(1, 2, 3, 4);
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I tries with c1,c2,c3,c4 => (1.1, null, null,null) and its not working

Comment: Ops, just a typo, should be `coalesce(c1, c2, c3)`. The answer edited.

Comment: Now it works for me ;D. Just my curiosity. Between Manuel Saucedo's answer above and your answer, which way is faster?

Comment: @Lester it does not matter

Comment: @Lester - I do not think there is a significant difference.

Comment: I see. Thank you all!